# Why has my auth.log file emptied - is this normal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, log-files

Just took a look at my server auth.log file for the first time in a few days, and noticed that it has **no entries** before 6:47 this morning.

This is really odd because I dumped that logfile to my laptop when I looked at it a couple of days before, and it was well over 2400 lines of cron jobs, break-in attempts etc.

When I ran `cat /var/log/auth.log` just now - I was expecting thousands of lines, and got about 50 lines of cron jobs, one break-in attempt and my latest ssh in.

Why has this happened? - Does Ubuntu periodically empty this file? Have I been hacked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a cronjob in /etc/cron.daily (in CentOS anyway, may be different in Ubuntu) to run a tool called logrotate, which reads configuration from /etc/logrotate.d and handles the aging of system logs, etc.

Typically, a weeks worth of logs are kept, rotated once daily.  In modern implementations, you will see other files named `/var/log/auth.log.[date]`.  Try doing:

```
ls -l /var/log/auth.log*
```

Answer (score 2):

There's log rotation, which happens typically in the morning (I believe the default is at or shortly after 06:25).  It looks like you pulled the file shortly after logrotate ran.

Depending on the logrotate configuration, the previous day's file will be named /var/log/auth.log.1.  Look for it there.

The logrotate configuration is in /etc/logrotate.d.  The cron job for logrotate is in /etc/cron.daily, with scripts in that directory being run from /etc/crontab.

Comment: On RHEL systems it's in cron.daily, at 4:02 AM.  This probably varies by distribution, though.

Comment: He tagged Ubuntu, so I looked at an Ubuntu box for the exact time.  The 6:25 run also matches up with the time he transferred the file.